# Continual error when trying to launch build for Quest 2

Tags: android, virtual-reality

Every time I try to launch this test game, using the available template, I get the following error: I changed only personal names in the following error to xxxx

`LogPlayLevel: Warning: WARNING: Error while enumerating Visual Studio toolchains LogPlayLevel: Warning: WARNING: Assuming no compilation capability. LogPlayLevel: Setting up ProjectParams for C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documents\Unreal Projects\xxxx_2_FPS\xxxx_2_FPS.uproject LogPlayLevel: xxxx_2_FPS.uproject requires a temporary target.cs to be generated (OculusOpenXR plugin is enabled) LogPlayLevel: ********** STAGE COMMAND STARTED ********** LogPlayLevel: Error: ERROR: Stage Failed. Missing receipt 'C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documents\Unreal Projects\xxxx_2_FPS\Binaries\Android\xxxx_2_FPS.target'. Check that this target has been built. LogPlayLevel:        (see C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.27\Log.txt for full exception trace) LogPlayLevel: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=103 (Error_MissingExecutable) LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Build Task, Time: 1.783225 LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Deploy Task, Time: 0.000043 LogPlayLevel: BUILD FAILED PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Missing UE4Game binary. You may have to build the UE4 project with your IDE. Alternatively, build using UnrealBuildTool with the commandline: UE4Game <Platform> <Configuration>`

Neither the software itself nor the Unreal forums throw any light on this. There is no explanation as to where or how I can fix the target.

I just want to be a game creator, I don't want to become a software engineer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Also I had to edit my tags, as I needed at least 1500 reputation apparently, instead of just needing a question to be answered.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if the recipient was build?

```
ERROR: Stage Failed. Missing receipt
'C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documents\Unreal Projects\xxxx_2_FPS\Binaries\Android\xxxx_2_FPS.target'.
Check that this target has been built
```